# Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' in flutter build apk --release

Tags: flutter, dart

flutter build apk --release is unable to build release apk of my Flutter application. It is giving the error for permission_handler plugin which is neither used nor declared in pubspec.yaml file. It gives the following output on running this command:

```html
D:\mobile>flutter build apk --release

 Building with sound null safety 

Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Note: C:\SDK\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-11.2.8\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\JobIntentService.java uses or overrides a deprecat
ed API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\SDK\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geocoding-2.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geocoding\GeocodingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\SDK\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.1.2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\Convert.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\SDK\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.12\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe oper
ations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
C:\SDK\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-6.1.3\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\ServiceManager.java:152: warning: [deprecation] getDefaultAdapte
r() in BluetoothAdapter has been deprecated
        final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                                                                  ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
1 warning

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           18.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

These are the dependencies Which are declared in my application:

```html
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons:
  google_maps_flutter:
  datetime_picker_formfield:
  flutter_svg:
  modal_progress_hud_nsn:
  http:
  cached_network_image:
  shared_preferences:
  firebase_auth:
  firebase_messaging:
  firebase_core:
  overlay_support:
  country_code_picker:
  dio:
  image_picker:
  flutter_image_compress:
  flutter_device_type:
  badges:
  sliding_up_panel:
  geolocator:
  google_maps_place_picker:
  lottie:
  tuple:
  encrypt:
  flutter_local_notifications:
  flutter_rating_bar:
  mask_text_input_formatter:
  url_launcher:
  flutter_staggered_grid_view:
  flutter_stripe:
  geocoding:
```

Whereas my compiledsdkversion is 32 and minsdkversion is 21:

```html
flutter.compiledSdkVersion=32
flutter.minSdkVersion=21
```

Anyone help me what is this issue and not building release apk.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I updated the kotlin version to ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10', in android\build.gradle